# Using a different tense in the same sentence in dependent clauses?

Tags: tenses

> God froze in time and lay quietly, heedless of the music of the
> birds as they **sing**.

I am wondering if the present can be used here, because sing is tied to the phrase "music of the bird" and not the dependent clause "froze in time and lay quietly". Also, can we use the present "sing" to stress that "God" is immortal?

You would usually use "sang", but I am wondering if "sing" is appropriate here.

Comment: Well, the past tense of _lie_ is _lay_, not _laid_, to start with. And the idiom is _heedless of_, not _heedless to_. And the last clause, _as they sing_, adds nothing to the sentence. The singing of the birds can only happen as they sing, so there's no information here. Don't worry about tenses; they're much less important than textbooks say. Pay attention to constructions and predicates -- they determine almost everything, in context.

Comment: Ok, fixed. I am still unsure about the tenses.

Comment: That's too bad. I still don't understand what the last clause is for, but I have no idea what's supposed to happen when god lies down.

Comment: I guess a sentence from a popular author doing this would convince me that this is not ungrammatical.

Comment: Literature isn't synonymous of grammatical though. Authors frequently will intentionally use ungrammatical ways to achieve new meanings of communication, new expressions, and more. That's the difference between grammar and linguistics. Grammar is documentation of the "proper usage of language on a given period of time", while Linguistics are the studies of the evolution of communication. These are very different things.